# Asking another thread to do something

Tags: python, multithreading, events, notifications, queue

I have one `Thread`(1) that's listening for input signals, and when it gets a signal another `Thread`(2) should do an action. I'm struggling with whether I should share a `Queue` between the two threads and put functions in it from (1) and getting them in (2) in a big while loop. Does `python` offer better ways of communicating functioncalls between threads?

Comment: Do you need to send the function, or just a signal of some kind telling Thread(2) to do something?

Comment: Basically just to tell Thread(2) to do something, that would invoke a function.

Comment: Should an action be performed by Thread(2) *each time* Thread(1) receives a signal, or should it perform an action if it happens to be waiting while Thread(1) receives a signal?

Comment: It should always perform the action, it's up to Thread(2) what it should do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a Queue.

If you were to use a [threading.Condition](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#condition-objects), or [threading.Event](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects), I don't think there is a way to tell the worker thread that there is more than one input to be processed.
The communication device they provide between threads is more like a toggle switch -- on or off, notify or waiting.

Thus, if Thread(2) were in the middle of processing a signal while Thread(1) received another signal, Thread(1) would not have a good way of telling Thread(2) that *another* signal had arrived. In contrast, a Queue would arrange all the ducks (signals) neatly in a row, and allow Thread(2) to process them one-by-one.

```
import threading
import datetime as DT
import time
import Queue
import random
import itertools

sentinel = None
def worker(queue):
    for date, count in iter(queue.get, sentinel):
        now = DT.datetime.now()
        print('{}: Signal found at {}, processed at {}'
              .format(count, date.strftime('%S.%f'), now.strftime('%S.%f')))
        time.sleep(random.random()*5)

queue = Queue.Queue()
t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(queue, ))
t.daemon = True
t.start()

c = 0
while True:
    if random.random() < 0.05:
        queue.put((DT.datetime.now(), c))
        c += 1
    if c >= 5:
        # Tell worker to quit
        queue.put(sentinel)
        t.join()
        break
```

will print something like

```
0: Signal found at 27.308544, processed at 27.308705
1: Signal found at 27.308585, processed at 30.379586
2: Signal found at 27.308601, processed at 35.174354
3: Signal found at 27.308607, processed at 36.649155
4: Signal found at 27.308622, processed at 37.234935
```

Notice the signals are all found/generated (in the main thread) around 27.3, but aren't processed (in the worker thread) until much later.

Comment: Thanks alot, I'll go with the queue.